# Query post Pagination Problem

Tags: wp-query, pagination

I am using following code for query post but I am not getting pagination link. Where is the problem of the following code.

```
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

    <?php 

        $arr = array(
            'post_type'     => 'post',
            'posts_per_page' => 3
        );

        $the_query = new WP_Query($arr);
     ?>

    <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

        <?php if ( is_home() && ! is_front_page() ) : ?>
            <header>
                <h1 class="page-title screen-reader-text"><?php single_post_title(); ?></h1>
            </header>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php
        // Start the loop.
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
            get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

        // End the loop.
        endwhile; ?>
        <div class="nav-previous alignleft"><?php  next_posts_link('Older Post'); ?></div>
        <div class="nav-next alignright"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts' ); ?></div>
    <?php

    wp_reset_postdata();

    endif;
    ?>

    </main><!-- .site-main -->
</div><!-- .content-area -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I go the solution. I have take variable name like $wp_query = new WP_Query($arr);  instate of  $the_query = new WP_Query($arr); So my working code should be

```
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

    <?php 
        // global $wp_query;

        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

        $arr = array(

            'post_type'     => 'post',
            'posts_per_page' => 3,
            'paged' => $paged
        );

        $wp_query = new WP_Query($arr);
     ?>

    <?php if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

        <?php if ( is_home() && ! is_front_page() ) : ?>
            <header>
                <h1 class="page-title screen-reader-text"><?php single_post_title(); ?></h1>
            </header>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php
        // Start the loop.
        while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
            get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

        // End the loop.
        endwhile; ?>
        <div class="nav-previous alignleft"><?php  next_posts_link('Older Post'); ?></div>
        <div class="nav-next alignright"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts' ); ?></div>
    <?php

    wp_reset_postdata();

    endif;
    ?>

    </main><!-- .site-main -->
</div><!-- .content-area -->
```

Comment: But there is another problem. If I use this custom template as static home page pagination is not working. Anybody can help me?